# Не получается отправить письмо

Tags: html, php

До сих пор не получил своего письма на почту, хотя скрипт работает правильно, подскажите в чем проблема?

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv = "content-type" content = "text/html; charset = utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action = "send.php" method = "POST">
<p>Введите имя: <br>
<input name = "name" type = "text" size = "40">
</p>
<p>Введите email: <br>
<input name = "email" type = "text" size = "40"><br><br>
</p>
<p>Введите сообщение: <br>
<textarea name = "message" rows = "10" cols = "45"></textarea><br><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Отправить!">
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email'];}
if (isset($_POST['message'])) {$message = $_POST['message'];} 
$address = "адрес почты получателя письма";
$sub = "Вам сообщение";
$mes = "Автор назвался: $name\nУказал свой адрес: $email\nСодержание письма: $message";
$verify = mail ($address, $sub, $mes,"content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$email");
if ($verify == 'true')
{
echo "<p>Сообщение отправлено";
}
else
{
echo "<p>Сообщение не отправлено";
}
?>
```

Comment: попробуйте убрать action = "send.php", у меня письмо отправляется

Comment: в смысле, перенести php код в файл html?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в настройках окружения в котором запускался скрипт.

- *nux - установить, sendmail. Или лучше настроить нормальный почтовый сервер.
- Window - не знаю кто на нем скрипты запускает, если же *nux

Comment: простите, не понял ваш ответ

Comment: точнее дело в том, что скрипт отработав, выдает что письмо отправлено, а на почту письмо так и не доходит

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что на машине не стоит и/или не настроено ПО, которое занимается транспортировкой в сеть почты.